# Website Payments Pro (Paypal) Iframe

Tags: magento, paypal

I’m using Magento CE 1.6.2 and am attempting to use Website Payments Pro system.

I go through the checkout process, select Paypal PRO link as my payment method, get the message “You will be required to enter your payment details after you place an order”, get to the page where I review the order that has the “Place Order” button on it.

When I click “Place Order” my expectation is to get the paypal button in a iframe form but nothing appear. The page never changes.

If I check in the back end the order appears in Magento as “Pending Payment”.

I should mention that I am doing this with a test PayPal account and that I called PayPal and they believe that all my settings are correct although I am unsure if I have the settings right.

Any thoughts on why I’m not being directed to a page to enter my payment info after clicking “Place Order”?  Is there a bug with the Website Payments Pro and Magento 1.6.2?

[image]
http://minus.com/lbkpOV6gikF0bs

I have enabled the DEBUG mode and I have read in the payment_hosted_pro.log a correct response of the PAYPAL API.

```
2012-04-05T23:10:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [url] => https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
    [BMCreateButton] => Array
        (
            [METHOD] => BMCreateButton
            [BUTTONCODE] => TOKEN
            [BUTTONTYPE] => PAYMENT
            [L_BUTTONVAR0] => subtotal=14.88
            [L_BUTTONVAR1] => tax=0.00
            [L_BUTTONVAR2] => shipping=5.00
            [L_BUTTONVAR3] => invoice=100000050
            [L_BUTTONVAR4] => address_override=false
            [L_BUTTONVAR5] => currency_code=EUR
            [L_BUTTONVAR6] => buyer_email=jdoe@gmail.com
            [L_BUTTONVAR7] => billing_first_name=John
            [L_BUTTONVAR8] => billing_last_name=Doe
            [L_BUTTONVAR9] => billing_city=New York
            [L_BUTTONVAR10] => billing_state=New York
            [L_BUTTONVAR11] => billing_zip=0000
            [L_BUTTONVAR12] => billing_country=US
            [L_BUTTONVAR13] => billing_address1=no street
            [L_BUTTONVAR14] => billing_address2=
            [L_BUTTONVAR15] => first_name=John
            [L_BUTTONVAR16] => last_name=Doe
            [L_BUTTONVAR17] => city=New York
            [L_BUTTONVAR18] => state=New York
            [L_BUTTONVAR19] => zip=0000
            [L_BUTTONVAR20] => country=US
            [L_BUTTONVAR21] => address1=no street
            [L_BUTTONVAR22] => address2=
            [L_BUTTONVAR23] => paymentaction=authorization
            [L_BUTTONVAR24] => notify_url=http://www.magento.it/paypal/ipn/
            [L_BUTTONVAR25] => cancel_return=http://www.magento.it/paypal/hostedpro/cancel/
            [L_BUTTONVAR26] => return=http://www.magento.it/paypal/hostedpro/return/
            [L_BUTTONVAR27] => lc=IT
            [L_BUTTONVAR28] => template=templateD
            [L_BUTTONVAR29] => showBillingAddress=false
            [L_BUTTONVAR30] => showShippingAddress=false
            [L_BUTTONVAR31] => showBillingEmail=false
            [L_BUTTONVAR32] => showBillingPhone=false
            [L_BUTTONVAR33] => showCustomerName=false
            [L_BUTTONVAR34] => showCardInfo=true
            [L_BUTTONVAR35] => showHostedThankyouPage=false
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [USER] => ****
            [PWD] => ****
            [SIGNATURE] => ****
            [BUTTONSOURCE] => Varien_Cart_WPP_IT
        )

    [response] => Array
        (
            [WEBSITECODE] => <form action="https://securepayments.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="HSS-IC0YjKMf1wXUUGEyDIpUTWddXlgnXvVl">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - Il sistema di pagamento online più facile e sicuro!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/it_IT/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

            [EMAILLINK] => https://securepayments.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=HSS-IC0YjKMf1wXUUGEyDIpUTWddXlgnXvVl
            [HOSTEDBUTTONID] => HSS-IC0YjKMf1wXUUGEyDIpUTWddXlgnXvVl
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2012-04-05T23:10:41Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => bb7df94045217
            [ACK] => Success
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [BUILD] => 2764190
        )

    [__pid] => 5980
)
```

Why I cannot see the Website Payments Pro form in the onepage checkout?

- Magento 1.6
- Fresh install
- No custom template installed

Regards

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED FINALLY

I have solved the tricly problem enabling the Debug mode in always in a fresh install, checked the right permissions of the files and folders and testing it to buying a test product in my catalog.

Take a look the /var/log folder I get in the system.log this message:

2012-04-06T06:39:06+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/paypal/hostedpro/iframe.phtml
I have checked the directory frontend/base/default/template/paypal/ and **there is not any hostedpro directory!! This is really odd in a fresh install of Magento!**

I have created the directory and uploaded just the frontend/base/default/template/paypal/hss/iframe.phtml file and now it works as well!

This is a real Magento Bug!!

Answer (score 0):

**For 1.7.0.2 you dont need a hostedpro directory..hss works fine**.Yet i faced this problem and took lot of time to successfully implement that...
First of all you have to `create a paypal account and a corresponding sandbox account`.
**In sandbox account click on profile** a `pop up` will appear..you will get all the information there like `account information,API credentials,funding,settings,products`...
[image]

use the email id as the associated paypal account,API credentials,and `most importantly go to product`s..`enable the checkbox of Payment pro`.If you dont enable this checkbox you cant use payment pro hosted solution or payment advance...you will get various types of errors..

And another important thing to remember is that `payment pro hosted solution is not available in every country`..its available in `HongKong`,`United kingdom`...etc `not available in USA`....  [check this page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/website-payments-pro-hosted-solution/)    like payment Advance is not available in every country..`its available in USA`...so first you have to check whether its available or not...depending upon that you have to create your sandbox account...like for `pro hosted solution create an account of UK or HK`..and for `payment advance create an account of USA`...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was in my custom theme. Try changing your theme to default and see what happens